# SQL: Add values to STDEVP calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table.

```
Key | Count | Amount  
----| ----- | ------ 
1   |     2 |   10  
1   |     2 |   15  
2   |     5 |    1  
2   |     5 |    2  
2   |     5 |    3  
2   |     5 |   50  
2   |     5 |   20  
3   |     3 |    5  
3   |     3 |    4  
3   |     3 |    5
```

Sorry I couldn't figure out who to make the above a table.

I'm running this on SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

I'd like the stdevp return of the amount columns but if the number of records is less than some value 'x' (there will never be more than x records for a given key), then I want to add zeros to account for the remainder.

For example, if 'x' is 6:

- for key 1, I need stdevp(10,5,0,0,0,0)
- for key 2, I need stdevp(1,2,3,50,20,0)
- for key 3, I need stdevp(5,4,5,0,0,0)

I just need to be able to add zeros to the calculation. I could insert records to my table, but that seems rather tedious.

Answer (score 0):

This seems complicated -- padding data for each key.  Here is one approach:

```
with xs as (
      select 0 as val, 1 as n
      union all
      select 0, n + 1
      from xs
      where xs.n < 6
     )
select k.key, stdevp(coalesce(t.amount, 0))
from xs cross join
     (select distinct key from t) k left join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by key) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
     on t.key = k.key and t.seqnum = xs.n
group by k.key;
```

The idea is that the `cross join` generates 6 rows for each key.  Then the left join brings in available rows, up to the maximum.

Comment: thanks @Gordon. I was delusionally hoping I could just do something like stdevp(amount,rep(0,6-count)), but a crossjoin to left join won't be too difficult. much appreciated.

Comment: @spielerspieler . . . `stdevp()` is an aggregation function that takes its values from multiple *rows*.  Your interpretation would be a very different function.

Comment: I'm aware of this, thank you. I was just hoping there was some way I could manipulate the function. I used cross join to left join no problem, only took me a couple minutes to write. I honestly didn't even know cross join was a thing but it makes sense completely. just like expand.grid in R. Thanks again much.